# Incorrect data passed to the render() method

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using Editor js in conjunction with localstorage and when I load the note for the first time or reload the note without any content inside it I get the error of Incorrect data passed to the render() method, but when adding anything in the editor and reload the page, this error no longer appears, this is my component:

```
const { id } = useParams();
const { note } = useContextFnc();
const editorInstance = useRef<EditorJS | null>(null);
const editorRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
const [content, setContent] = useState<any>(null);

const handleEditorChange = (
    editor: MutableRefObject<EditorJS | null>,
    note: any
) => {
    if (!editor.current) return;
    editor.current
        .save()
        .then((outputData) => {
            Object.assign(note, outputData);
            localStorage.setItem("note", JSON.stringify(note));
        })
        .catch((error) => {});
};

useEffect(() => {
    const config: EditorConfig = {
        placeholder: "Document your inspirations...",
        holder: "editor",
        onChange: () => handleEditorChange(editorInstance, note),
        tools: {
            header: {
                class: Header,
                inlineToolbar: true,
            },
            list: {
                class: List,
                inlineToolbar: true,
            },
            paragraph: {
                class: Paragraph,
                inlineToolbar: true,
            },
        },
    };
    editorInstance.current = new EditorJS(config);
    return () => {
        if (editorInstance.current) {
            editorInstance.current.destroy();
            editorInstance.current = null;
        }
    };
}, []);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (editorInstance.current && content) {
            editorInstance.current.isReady
                .then(() => {
                    editorInstance.current?.render(content) 
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        }
    }, [content]);

useEffect(() => {


    const storedData = JSON.parse(
        window.localStorage.getItem("note") || "{}"
    );

    if(storedData){
        setContent(storedData);
    }else{
        setContent("")
    }

}, [id]);

return (
    <SectionNote data-testid="note-alone">
        <ContainerTexts>
            <TitleNote>{note?.titleNote}</TitleNote>
            <AssigneeNote>
                {note?.assigneeNote
                    ? `${note?.assigneeNote}`
                    : "Unassigned"}
            </AssigneeNote>
        </ContainerTexts>
        <OptionColors>
            <TextArea id="editor" ref={editorRef}></TextArea>
        </OptionColors>
    </SectionNote>
);
```

I tried to condition the content to verify that there is something inside it, but I did not find a solution to my problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.